# maths problem with absolute numbers and complex conjugates

Tags: complex-numbers

With the following expression with complex conjugates $$ -xx^{*}+yy^{*} = -|x|^2 + |y|^2$$ can it be represented as $$|x|^2 - |y|^2$$ or since $ |x|^2 + |y|^2 = 2$ is it true that $|x|^2 - |y|^2 = |y|^2 -|x|^2 $ is it only true if the 2 is $|2|$?

Comment: I changed the tag, but you should probably edit the question a little, so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confusing - for instance, it is not clear why you say that $|x|^2+|y|^2 =2$, but one thing is certain: $|2|$ is the same number as 2, so it can never be the case that "... is only true if the 2 is $|2|$".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but the answer to "is it true that $|x|^2−|y|^2=|y|^2−|x|^2$" is *no*.

A counterexample: let $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = 0$ so that $|x|^2 + |y^2| = 2$ as required. Then $|x|^2 - |y|^2 = 2$ and $|y|^2 - |x|^2 = -2$.